# A question related to a Jordan curve : Is there an elementary proof?

Tags: general-topology, curves

Let $f : [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be a Jordan curve, $\textit{i.e.}$,
$f$ is an injective continuous function with $f(0) = f(1)$.

Let $C$ be the set $f([0,1])$.

Assume that $p$ is an arbitrary point in $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus C$.

Let $S(p)$ denote the set $\{ \, |f(t) - p| \, : \, ~ 0 \leq t \leq 1 \, \}$, $\textit{i.e.}$,
$S(p)$ is the collection of lengths from $p$ to any points in $C$.

Then it is clear that $S(p) \subset (0, \infty)$.

**It is my question : Is there an elementary way to prove that $0 < \inf S(p)$?**

It is equivalent that we can choose a small ball $B(p;r)$, the ball whose center is $p$
and radius is $r$, which is contained in $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus C$.

In other words, if we can prove that $C$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then this problem is proved.

Comment: Continuous image of a compact set is compact.

Comment: “Injective” and $f(0)=f(1)$ are contradictory. But we know what you mean.

Comment: The continuous image of a compact set is compact. $S(p)$ is such a set.